# How to clear the list when response is false

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="con in connectionArray"  ng-if="con.account_type=='user'">
    <p style="display:inline-block;width:160px;" class="con_name">
        <img class="teamImg" ng-src="{{ con.account_image }}">
        <span class="con_item">Profile: </span>
        <span class="con_user">{{ con.account_name }}</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

**angularjs**

```
yourteamService.listConnections(args).then(function(response) {
    if(!response.status){
        alert("No Connections");
    }else{
        $scope.connectionArray = response.accounts;
    }
    $scope.getListTeams = false;
}, 
function(response) {
});
```

Here I can list connections using $scope.connectionArray. I need to clear the connections list when response is false. How to do this.

Comment: do you mean to wipe out the array? $scope.connectionArray = [ ] ?

Comment: yes, and I need to clear the previous result in html

Comment: So the code above should work

Answer (score 0):

As @Jax said, you should:

```
if(!response.status){
    alert("No Connections");
    $scope.connectionArray = [];
}
```

Also I suggest you user the `.success()` and `.error()` instead of `.then()`, assuming you are calling an API in your service. That way you can get rid of the hassle of handling the HTTP response too.

Hope this helps!

Here is a helpful link I found: http://www.peterbe.com/plog/promises-with-$http

Answer (score 0):

The ng-repeat create a lot of listeners everywhere in your page. So if your array takes the [] value, Angular will catch it and reload your page immediatly.
Just, if you allow me to give you an advice : try to use ng-show instead of ng-if. ng-if shows your HTML element if the statement is true (same as ng-show). But ng-show load the element. Ng-if not.
It can prevent you some errors wich could be hard to find out later.